# How to embed python module in a script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script meant to run as a standalone tool invoked via:

python tool.py

This requirement for this tool is that it remain a standalone script. The issue I'm running into is that I'm replying heavily on a module, namely pexpect, and since it's not part of the standard python library I can't ask users to install the module via pip or any other means and then run my script.

The script in question is a commandline tool. Is there any way for me to package my script in such a way that it pulls in the code from pexpect module? I've tried py2app etc to no avail. This tool is meant to run on macs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Generally even command line scripts would be installed via a setup.py file. Just list your dependency in your setup.py file and when your users install your script the dependency will be installed for them. Any reason why that won't work?

Comment: The requirement was that it be a standalone file. I was able to get around it by just pulling in the code for the module itself.

Comment: Just make sure you are not violating any software licenses and/or you have permission of the module's author. At the very least you might need a comment which properly attributes the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the pexpect module in the directory where you have the tool.py and the import should work just fine.

Comment: While this works, you may have licensing issues and you need to be sure that you only have the library, not the package of which the library is a part.